# Триггер, отслеживающий изменение баланса

Tags: php, mysql, триггер

Есть таблица users с полями `uid`, `cash` и `points` и др.
Есть еще одна таблица `exchange_log` с полями `userid`, `summa` и др.
Нужно создать триггер который отслеживает перевода суммы с `cash` на `points` и записывает сумму перевода и `id` пользователя(`uid`) на таблицу `exchange_log`.
Вот что я пробовал но не работает:

```
CREATE TRIGGER exchange_log
    AFTER UPDATE ON users
    FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.cash != OLD.cash AND NEW.points != OLD.points AND
   (NEW.points-OLD.points) = (OLD.cash - NEW.CASH))
THEN
  INSERT INTO exchange_log(uid, summa) VALUES(NEW.uid,NEW.points-OLD.points);
END IF
```

Отредактируйте триггер и покажите мою ошибку. Спасибо.

Comment: Правильно ли я указал условия отслеживания изменения только в столбцах cash и points? или нужно еще указать другие столбцы? Например: New.uid = OLD.uid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в таблице `exchange_log` внешний ключ пользователя называется `userid`, его нужно указать в конструкции `INSERT INTO` вместо `uid`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER exchange_log
AFTER UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.cash != OLD.cash AND NEW.points != OLD.points AND
   (NEW.points-OLD.points) = (OLD.cash - NEW.CASH))
THEN
  INSERT INTO exchange_log(userid, summa) VALUES(NEW.uid,NEW.points-OLD.points);
END IF//
```

После этого у меня триггер заработал так, как вы описываете.

Comment: Правильно ли я указал условия? Нужно ли мне проверить, что другие столбцы не изменяются, Если я хочу чтобы триггер заработал только тогда когда изменяются только две столбцы(cash и points)? @cheops

Comment: @ShuhratjonJumaev да, с условиями все в порядке. Погонял триггер, все корректно.